# What is in-memory preallocation range in ext4 file system

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems

I'm reading a paper called [Ext4 block and inode allocator improvements](http://landley.net/kdocs/ols/2008/ols2008v1-pages-263-274.pdf), in which the author mentions

> Like Ext3 reservation, Ext4 maintains an in-memory preallocation
>   range for each file, and uses that to solve the fragmentation
>   issues caused by concurrent allocation.

But I can't find any detailed information about the in-memory preallocation range.

According to my understanding of this paper, when the block allocator allocates blocks to a **LARGE** file, it will firstly try to allocate blocks referred by the *in-memory preallocation space*. if the space is not sufficient, it then will look at the *per-block-group buddy cache*. But I don't understand how does ext4 maintain the preallocation space, how does it calculate the size of the space to be preallocated for the next allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does ext4 maintain the preallocation space

As per the [documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/mballoc.c) of ext4 the preallocation space is maintained at two places:

1. per inode.
2. per locality/CPU group

   For *small* (while allocation is being done or post allocation) files prealloc blocks from per locality group are picked, for large files those from inode are referred.

> how does it calculate the size of the space to be preallocated for the next allocation?

From the ext4 documentation:

> Before allocating blocks via buddy cache we normalize the request
> blocks. This ensure we ask for more blocks that we needed. The extra
> blocks that we get after allocation is added to the respective prealloc
> list.

More details of the allocation algorithm (eg. how normalization of a alloc request is done) are explained quite well in the liked header file.